# Why the same memory location holding different values at the same time?

Tags: c++

How could the same memory location hold different values in the following program?
I am using g++ compiler.

code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   const int i=100;
   int *j = const_cast<int*>(&i);
   *j=1;

   cout<<"The value of i is:"<<i<<endl;
   cout<<"The value j holds:"<<*j<<endl;
   cout<<"The address of i is:"<<&i<<endl;
   cout<<"The address of j is:"< <j<<endl;

}
```

output:

```
The value of i is:100
The value j holds:1
The address of i is:0xbffbe79c
The address of j is:0xbffbe79c
```

Comment: Well, you kind of invoked the C++ gods' wrath when you modified it.

Comment: The compiler is more likely optimizing your use of `i` and using the value `100` directly on your `cout` statement. Modifying a const variable is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Also, what @chris said :-)

Comment: Your code has a bug, so of course it's not going to do what you expect it to do! Fix the bug and the mystery will go away.

Comment: "Undefined behaviour is undefined"

Comment: You lied to the compiler, so it lied to you. Honesty is the best policy.

Comment: Also, you print out the address of i and the value of j, which is the adress of i. If you want to print the adress of j you should add the adress operator when printing the value... ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got undefined behavior, so anything can happen.  In this case, the compiler knows that `i` cannot change value, and probably just uses the value directly.

Comment: I'm no expert in undefined-behavior-omancy, but I feel like if you dereferenced its address, you'd get the modified value.

Comment: As I keep seeing mentioned over and over in "Secure Coding in C and C++", once you've invoked undefined behavior, the compiler is free to do anything it wants, including nothing at all.

Comment: @Wug _If_ you dereference an address, you will get the value at that address.  But in this case, the compiler is free to assume that the value of `i` never changes.  Since it knows the value can only be `100`, it just uses the constant `100`.  Another possibility is that the compiler put the variable `i` in read only memory, and `*j = 1;` causes the program to crash.  One of the points of "undefined behavior" is that the compiler is free to assume that it doesn't occur, and optimize in consequence.

Answer (score 4):

The memory cannot hold different values at the same time. But, modifying an object that was declared `const` is *undefined-behavior* so anything can happen.

*Anything* includes making it look like the same memory location is holding different values at the same time. What happens is that since `i` cannot be changed, it is a candidate for *constant folding*, so there isn't any memory involved when `i` appears in an expression.